# How do I undo File System changes made in my Rails/RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec2

In my Rails/Rspec tests I'm CRUD'ing file resources. I'd like to be able to undo any of those changes after my tests complete the same way that database changes are undone with transactions.

1. If I add a file for a test, I'd like to have the file removed after
   the test.
2. If I modify a file for a test, I'd like have the file
   restored to its prior state after the test.
3. If I delete a file for a test, I'd like to have the file restored

Is there a feature in RSpec or perhaps a different Gem that monitors file system changes and can restore to a previous state? Or must I undo these changes manually?

I'm currently running Rails3, RSpec2, and Capybara.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any tools that do exactly what you are looking for but one way to do this might be to do the following:
1. Add a before(:all) hook to your spec_helper.rb that tars up the directory structure you want to restore after each test
2. Add before(:each) and after(:all) hooks in your spec_helper.rb that do an rm -r on your directory structure and then un-tar the files

Another, possibly more efficient way to do this might be to use rsync instead of tar.  I believe rsync is smarter about only overwriting changes that need to be overwritten.

I believe this would accomplish your goal.  The bad thing is that if the tests are aborted you would have to manually untar the files.

Actually, this sounds like a great idea for a project on github if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: +1 for reading my mind on all three ideas. Thats the exact train of thought I went through. Especially the github project. I'm surprised it's not out there.

Answer (score 5):

I took Brian John's advice on all of his points, but I thought that I'd post some code from my solution in case anyone else was looking to do something similar. I also added a check for a custom metadata tag, so that I only do this when I flag a test group with a *:file* symbol

**spec_helper.rb**

Note that below I'm backing up my `#{Rails.root}public/system/ENV/files` directory (where ENV = "test" or "develop") because I'm using this for testing paperclip functionality and that's where my files get stored.

Also, instead of just doing an `rm -r` on the directory structure I'm restoring with the `--delete` rysnc command from my backup file, which will remove any files that were created during the test.

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # So we can tag tests with our own symbols, like we can do for ':js'
  # to signal that we should backup and restore the filesystem before
  config.treat_symbols_as_metadata_keys_with_true_values = true

  config.before(:each) do
    # If the example group has been tagged with the :file symbol then we'll backup
    # the /public/system/ENV directory so we can roll it back after the test is over
    if example.metadata[:file]
      `rsync -a #{Rails.root}/public/system/#{Rails.env}/files/ #{Rails.root}/public/system/#{Rails.env}/files.back`
    end
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    # If the example group has been tagged with the file symbol then we'll revert
    # the /public/system/ENV directory to the backup file we created before the test
    if example.metadata[:file]
      `rsync -a --delete #{Rails.root}/public/system/#{Rails.env}/files.back/ #{Rails.root}/public/system/#{Rails.env}/files/`
    end
  end
end
```

**sample_spec.rb**

Note that I've tagged the *it "should create a new file"* with the *:file* symbol

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Lesson Player", :js => true do

  it "should create a new file", :file do
    # Do something that creates a new file
    ...
  end

end
```